MessagePack Serialization With and Without Type Information
Consider the following code, which implements MessagePack serialization:
MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(value, Options);

For some reason, when value is defined as T, MessagePack includes the type information, however...
MessagePackSerializer.Serialize((object?)value, Options);

...now that I have cast (object?)value, MessagePack omits the type information.
Why is this?
